# Combine two Sub VBAs to run at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

How do I get these two Subs to run once. I've been trying to get the call sub function to work but I know im just screwed this up

```
Sub DeleteSelectedColumns()
Dim currentColumn As Integer
Dim columnHeading As String
'
For currentColumn = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1
    columnHeading = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells(6, currentColumn).Value
'Check whether to preserve the column
    Select Case columnHeading
    'Insert name of columns to preserve
        Case "DriverNo", "POD Name"
            'Do nothing
        Case Else
            'Delete the column
            ActiveSheet.Columns(currentColumn).Delete
        End Select
    Next
    '
  Call Sub sorthisfield
    End Sub
   '
Sub sortthisfield()
'
Sortthisfield Macro
'
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("A6:A286"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Order Data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Call` keyword should be considered deprecated. Replace `Call Sub sorthisfield` with simply `sorthisfield`

Comment: I got an error 
https://ibb.co/v4rB6Xn

Comment: In your screenshot, the name is misspelled. That's why it's not defined.

Comment: These subs seems to be independent. If so сreate "wrapping" procedure that calls first of your subs, then the second one, and remove inter-calling.

Comment: @RajeshS Not sure why you pinged me - that's not "my" macro.

Comment: @Comintern,, sorry by mistake I've had Pinged you, It was for #ndocds.

Comment: @ndocds, your First Macro has some fault and it Deletes all Columns rather than few specific. Also, I'm unable to understand what you are suppose to perform with Second Macro. Better make is clear whether you want to Filter the Sort or Sort the Filter and what would be the Key!!